# Google Maps PNG overlay in IE

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm running a Google Map which loads png images from server, stores them in an array and when needed, creates and shows animation of these images. As they are png images, I have issues with IE transparency support. I know about IEPNGFix.htc script, but I don't think it can be used in this situation. From what I've read it is only applicable to DOM elements. Is there a way to apply png transparency fix for these images?

Google doesn't help neither (although i would expect this to be a common problem). If you have any idea how to solve this, let me know.

Comment: Can you show us a site that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: http://www.zimmi.cz/edpp/ there is a black boundary line in IE 7 that is not present in other browsers. That line is obviously not that bad, but assuming some people may view the site with IE 6...

Comment: V3 does not support IE6. It may work on IE6, but Google doesn't make any effort to accommodate it. Sounds like pngfix may be the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call PNGFix on any element after it has been added to the page. See here:

http://pjdietz.com/jquery-plugins/pngfix/

You will need to hook into the event which is fired after the image has been displayed on the google map and then apply the pngfix to that new element.

Comment: _PNGFix works with img elements and CSS backgrounds._
Are you sure it can be used to GroundOverlay object?